# Why do we have two ways to include serde_derive?

Tags: rust, serde

I am learning rust serde library now and want to understand is there any difference between these two ways to include Serialization / Deserialization features

What is the proper way (is using in production code)?

Example 1

```
# Cargo.toml

serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
```

I this case I have to use `use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};` )

Example 2

```
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
serde = {version="1.0.117"}
serde_derive = {version="1.0.117"}
```

I this case I have to use `use serde_derive::{Deserialize, Serialize};` )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The common way is to include `serde` and enable the `derive` feature. This way, you only have one direct dependency, you don't need to worry about mismatch in `serde` and `serde-derive` versions, and you can use the derive macros directly from `serde`.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the first syntax:

```ini
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
```

It is the way shown in [the Serde documentation](https://serde.rs/derive.html#using-derive).

---

For technical reasons, crates exporting procedural macros (like `#[derive]`s) must be a separate crate. If not for that, there likely wouldn't be a serde-derive crate at all.

And the derive macros are feature-gated by `"derive"` because in some cases where you don't need it, you can save compilation time by omitting it and other crates that aid in creating procedural macros (syn, quote, etc.).

As separate dependencies, you also run the risk of the interface (serde) and the generator (serde-derive) being out-of-sync and generating wrong or suboptimal implementations. I don't see this happening for serde in particular since its very stable, but its possible (like using `strum = "0.25"` but `strum_macros = "0.24"`). Allowing one to re-export the other ensures they stay compatible.